# ENTER key in TeXstudio macro trigger

Tags: macros, texstudio

I have just discovered macros in TeXstudio and I want to create one that is triggered by a specific text (namely: `/ma`) followed by the Enter key.

So far, I've tried using `\/ma\r`, `\/ma\n`, `\/ma\r\n` as the trigger, but none of them worked right.

Is it possible to use the Enter key as part of the macro trigger? How do I do that?

Comment: This is probably a question for https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you was after, however, this solution might be helpful as well.

You can make use of `Abbreviation` in macros, so that it appears in auto-completion list that can be triggered via <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Therefore, if the abbreviation begins with `\` character, you can get what you wanted.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @antshar, sadly I need the command to start with the other slash...